# Something is wrong with io_export_md3.py

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, conversion

I try to export mesh to md3 format using script taken from here:
http://www.katsbits.com/smforum/index.php?topic=326.0

The upper and middle part of the test model is exported without errors. The problem occurs when I try to export the bottom part (l_legs). The contents of the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons\io_export_md3.py", line 792, in execute
    save_md3(settings)
  File "C:\Users\...\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons\io_export_md3.py", line 745, in save_md3
    md3.Save(file)
  File "C:\Users\...\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons\io_export_md3.py", line 404, in Save
    s.Save(file)
  File "C:\Users\...\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons\io_export_md3.py", line 258, in Save
    v.Save(file)
  File "C:\Users\...\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons\io_export_md3.py", line 109, in Save
    data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0], tmpData[1], tmpData[2], tmpData[3])
struct.error: short format requires SHRT_MIN <= number <= SHRT_MAX

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I have only basic knowledge of Phyton and I can't understand what is wrong. 
The test model is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5-IgQ5NZvSrSTZuWFhpRlF0aGs)

Comment: I've been experimenting with the model and found the cause of the error. The size of the entire model must not exceed the dimensions 1000 x 1000 units